# Cache wrapper for DB model

Tags: php, laravel, caching

I have been trying to find the best way to create a cache wrapper for all models. So all the DB lookup are done through the model, but the model decides if the results should be stored in cache.

For example, when I search for a user by email, I want to do something like `User->getByEmail('test@exmaple.com');`

My User model would contain a function that looks something like

```
public static function getByEmail($email) {
    $cache = self::cacheFetch($email);
    if($cache) {
        return $cache;
    }
    // DB lookup to get data
    self::cacheStore($email, $data);
    return $data;
}
```

`cacheFetch` and `cacheStore` are defined as traits. The App name and table name are prepended to the cache key to avoid key clash.

How do I do the database lookup within the Model?

Is there a better way to achieve what I am trying to do here?

Answer (score 0):

You actually only need one function, `cacheFetch`. This function would check if the queried data is in cache and if not, load the data from the database.

This is a small example of how the function could work:

```
protected function cacheFetch($email)
{
    $slug = 'db_' . self::getTable() . '_' . $email;

    // Try fetching data from cache
    if (cache()->has($slug)) {
        return cache($slug);
    }

    // Fetch data from database and put in cache
    $data = self::where('email', $email)->get();
    cache()->put($slug, $data, 60);

    return $data;
}
```